# Getting an exception when I press my FlotaingButton or AppBar IconButton. I already Add a Scffold in _MyAppHomePage

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (No Scaffold widget found.
MyHomePage widgets require a Scaffold widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a Scaffold ancestor was:
MyHomePage
The ancestors of this widget were:
Semantics
Builder
RepaintBoundary-[GlobalKey#5c844]
IgnorePointer
AnimatedBuilder
FadeTransition
FractionalTranslation
SlideTransition
_FadeUpwardsPageTransition
AnimatedBuilder
RepaintBoundary
FocusTrap
_FocusMarker
Semantics
FocusScope
PrimaryScrollController
_ActionsMarker
Actions
Builder
PageStorage
Offstage
_ModalScopeStatus
UnmanagedRestorationScope
RestorationScope
AnimatedBuilder
_ModalScope-[LabeledGlobalKey<_ModalScopeState>#c4e87]
Semantics
_EffectiveTickerMode
TickerMode
_OverlayEntryWidget-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryWidgetState>#becc1]
_Theatre
Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#3a815]
UnmanagedRestorationScope
_FocusMarker
Semantics
FocusScope
AbsorbPointer
Listener
HeroControllerScope
Navigator-[GlobalObjectKey _WidgetsAppState#0ccea]
IconTheme
IconTheme
_InheritedCupertinoTheme
CupertinoTheme
_InheritedTheme
Theme
AnimatedTheme
_ScaffoldMessengerScope
ScaffoldMessenger
Builder
DefaultTextStyle
CustomPaint
Banner
CheckedModeBanner
Title
Directionality
_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#ed058]
Semantics
Localizations
MediaQuery
_MediaQueryFromWindow
_FocusMarker
Focus
_FocusTraversalGroupMarker
FocusTraversalGroup
_ActionsMarker
DefaultTextEditingActions
_ActionsMarker
Actions
_ShortcutsMarker
Semantics
_FocusMarker
Focus
DefaultTextEditingShortcuts
_ShortcutsMarker
Semantics
_FocusMarker
Focus
Shortcuts
UnmanagedRestorationScope
RestorationScope
UnmanagedRestorationScope
RootRestorationScope
WidgetsApp-[GlobalObjectKey _MaterialAppState#d0f4a]
Semantics
_FocusMarker
Focus
HeroControllerScope
ScrollConfiguration
MaterialApp
MyApp
[root]
Typically, the Scaffold widget is introduced by the MaterialApp or WidgetsApp widget at the top of your application widget tree.)
getting this exception when I click my app FlotaingButton or AppButton.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './widgets/new_transaction.dart';
import './widgets/transaction_list.dart';
import './models/transaction.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: 't1',
      title: 'New Shoes',
      amount: 60.32,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      id: 't2',
      title: ' Weekly Groceriese',
      amount: 10.22,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  void _addNewTransaction(String txTitle, double txAmount) {
    final newTx = Transaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: DateTime.now(),
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );
    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  void _startNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showBottomSheet(
        context: ctx,
        builder: (_) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed:  () =>  _startNewTransaction(context),
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.blue,
                elevation: 5,
                child: Text('Chart !'),
              ),
            ),
            TransactionList(_userTransactions),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _startNewTransaction(context),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[I also tried this way by using Scaffold.of(ctx).showBottomSheet but its giving me some error which I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPVcK.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `showModalBottomSheet` instead.

Or if You wish to use `showBottomSheet` then this is a workaround.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: Scaffold(body: MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _startNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showBottomSheet(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(),
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => _startNewTransaction(context),
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.blue,
                elevation: 5,
                child: Text('Chart !'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _startNewTransaction(context),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thnx sir, now it's working perfectly. @Josteve